# Splitting a string at every 2 newline characters in haskell

Tags: regex, string, haskell, text

My input looks like

```
abc

a
b
c

abc
abc
abc
abc
```

I need a function that would split it into something like

```hs
[ "abc"
, "a\nb\nc"
, "abc\nabc\nabc\nabc"]
```

I've tried using regexes, but

1. I can't import `Text.Regex` itself
2. `Module Text.Regex.Base` does not export `splitStr`

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to use regex in such cases, since it's less readable then pure and concise code, that can be used here.

For example using `foldr`, the only case where we should add new string into lists of strings is the case where last seen element and current element are `newline`'s:

```
split :: FilePath -> IO [String]
split path = do
    text <- readFile path
    return $ foldr build [[]] (init text)
        where 
            build c (s:ls) | s == [] || head s /= '\n' || c /= '\n' = (c:s)       : ls  
                           | otherwise                              = [] : tail s : ls
```

This code produces the aforementioned result when it is given file with aforementioned content.